# text replacing in data file with peculiar spacing

Tags: text-processing, replace, text

I have a text (`.qdp`) file with many data stored.
In some rows, the data are too many to be on just one line. Then, the program that saves the data, use a minus sign (`-`) to go on the new line, and continue the data writing, with two blank spaces at the beginning of the new line.
How can I `find and replace` the minus plus the two blank spaces, in order to rewrite the data without any interruption?
This is an example of what I have:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7-
  8 9 10
```

And here what I want:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem this should work:

```
sed '/-$/ {N;s/-\n  / /}' your_file.qdp
```

Comment: Yep, it is this. How can I do it into the `.qdp` file?

Comment: @Py-ser -  `sed '/-$/ {N;s/-\n  / /}' your_file.qdp > new_file.qdp`

Comment: So, must I create a new file?

Comment: @Py-ser You can use `sed -i`  if you really want to replace directly in original file.

Comment: use `-i` instead: sed -i.bak'/-$/ {N;s/-\n  / /}' your_file.qdp

Comment: Sorry, is this ok for a file where the sostitution must be made for many lines (and not just one)?

Comment: @Py-ser If by many lines you mean that there are many split lines then yes, this should work.

Comment: Thanks. Some lines are splitted, some others are not.